Limit of probability of $k$ successes in $n$ Bernoulli trials as $n \rightarrow \infty$
I'm trying to prove that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \binom{n}{k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k} = 0,
\end{equation}
for some natural number $k$ and $p \in (0,1)$.
This seems very natural to me, as I guess the probability of $k$ successes should go to zero as the number of trials goes to infinity, but I'm not sure how to make this mathematically precise.
Also, I'm wondering if the function
\begin{equation}
f(n) := \sum\limits_{k=0}^L \binom{n}{k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}, \quad n = L, L+1, \dots
\end{equation}
where $L$ is some natural number, is decreasing as $n$ increases. This also seems reasonable, as the probability of achieving less than or equal to $L$ successes should be decreasing as the number of trial increases.

Write $q=1-p\in(0,1)$. Then the wanted limit is up to a constant factor ($k!$ is fixed, and $(p/q)^k$ is also fixed) the limit for $n\to \infty$ from $$n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1)\cdot q^n\ .$$ The first part is polynomial in $n$, so we generalize it to a polynomial $P(n)$. The second part has exponential decay. Induction on $k$ now.

Just in case, I'd separate these two questions into different posts, but here's my answer to your first question.
To show $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \binom{n}{k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k} = 0$, we can look for an upper bound function and investigate if its limit converges to $0$.
Firstly, we can look to the binomial bracket term first. We have
\begin{align*}
    \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} &\leq \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)}{k!}\\
    &\leq \frac{n(n)(n)...(n)}{k!} = \frac{n^k}{k!}
\end{align*}
For a fixed $k$, $p^k$ will simply be a constant so we're good there.
For $(1-p)^{n-k}$, we need to investigate a little. We can adjust this term using exponential laws as such
\begin{align*}
    (1-p)^{n-k} &= e^{(n-k)\log(1-p)}
\end{align*}
From here, we can note that because $0 < p < 1 \implies \log(1-p) <0$, and hence this term will for large values of $n$ tend towards the function $e^{-n}$. Now let's put this altogether:
\begin{align}
    \binom{n}{k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \leq \frac{n^k}{k!}p^k e^{(n-k)\log(1-p)}
\end{align}
We have two components of this function which will be impacted by the limit. We know from limit laws thar $n^k$ will increase polynomially, however our exponent of $e^{(n-k)\log(1-p)}$ will tend towards $-\infty$, and as such, the entire term will tend towards $0$, outpacing the $n^k$ term. Everything else can be treated as constants and as the limit increases becomes obsolete.
Since our upper bound function converges to $0$ and our original function is non-negative by definition, we can apply the sandwich theorem:
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 0 &\leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \binom{n}{k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^k}{k!}p^k e^{(n-k)\log(1-p)}\\
0 &\leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \binom{n}{k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \leq 0\\
&\therefore \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \binom{n}{k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k} = 0\\
\end{align*}
Hope that helps :)

Very clear, thanks! :)
